# Characters encoding

Tags: php, mysql, encoding

I have problem with string encoding, in my DB I have string "pomarańczy" which is represented by "pomarańczy" as it is, but when I want to use it in php i get weird char codes as below

[image: characters encoding]

And my question is is this fault of my editor? I am using Sublime Text 3 on Fedora 22. Or is this fault of my database (mysql, InnoDB). Database is encoded with "utf8_general_ci", this specific column with "utf8_polish_ci".

Comment: utf-8 can be a pain. Have you read [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through) already?

Comment: No, I did not. I will write it asap and let you know if it helped. Thanks

Comment: How did you type that string?  Or did it come from somewhere?  Can you provide it in machine-readable form (not an image)?

Comment: Check the settings in Sublime Text 3.

Comment: It came from database if I copy it into browser it gets normal form. I want to have it without national chars so i have created array to translate them but it does not recognize all the chars but this char is in my array